# Match up to the comma - Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have created a Regex Pattern `(?<=[TCC|TCC_BHPB]\s\d{3,4})[-_\s]\d{1,2}[,]`
This Pattern match just:

```
TCC 6005_5,
```

What should I change to the end to match these both strings:

```
TCC 6005-5 ,
TCC 6005_5,
```

Comment: Do you only allow spaces or do you allow any character after the last digit, so long as it ends with a comma?

Comment: @Llama I want to get a match from the last number for ex. from -5 up to ,

Comment: You can match the optional space at the end before the comma `(?<=TCC(?:_BHPB)?\s\d{3,4})[-_\s]\d{1,2} ?,` See https://regex101.com/r/ByZPSE/1

Comment: Use `(?<=(?:TCC|TCC_BHPB)\s\d{3,4})[-_\s]\d{1,2}\s*,`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3aTCC%7cTCC_BHPB%29%5cs%5cd%7b3%2c4%7d%29%5b-_%5cs%5d%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%5cs*%2c&i=TCC+6005-5+%2c%0d%0aTCC+6005_5%2c). Or, `(?<=TCC(?:_BHPB)?\s\d{3,4})[-_\s]\d{1,2}\s*,`. If there can be any text between the digit and `,` use `(?<=TCC(?:_BHPB)?\s\d{3,4})[-_\s]\d{1,2}[^,]*,` (the last `,` can even be removed if it can go missing).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a non-greedy wildcard to your expression (`.*?`):

```
(?<=(?:TCC|TCC_BHPB)\s\d{3,4})[-_\s]\d{1,2}.*?[,]
                                           ^^^
```

This will now also match any characters between the last digit and the comma.

As has been pointed out in the comments, `[TCC|TCC_BHPB]` is a character class rather than a literal match, so I've changed this to `(?:TCC|TCC_BHPB)` which is presumably what your intention was.

[Try it online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3aTCC%7cTCC_BHPB%29%5cs%5cd%7b3%2c4%7d%29%5b-_%5cs%5d%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d.*%3f%5b%2c%5d&i=TCC+6005-5+%2c%0d%0aTCC+6005_5%2c)

Comment: Not my dv, but this part `[TCC|TCC_BHPB]` should be `(?:TCC|TCC_BHPB)` or else it is a character class matching one of the listed characters, or even `(?<=TCC(?:_BHPB)?`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hmm. I just took OP at their word that the rest of their expression was working correctly, but you're right. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the pattern `[TCC|TCC_BHPB]` is a character class that matches one of the listed characters. It might also be written for example as `[|_TCBHP]`

To "match" both strings, you can match all parts instead of using a positive lookbehind.

```
\bTCC(?:_BHPB)?\s\d{3,4}[-_\s]\d{1,2}\s?,
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xg9XZN/1)

- `\bTCC` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, then match `TCC`
- `(?:_BHPB)?\s\d{3,4}` Optionally match `_BHPB`, match a whitespace char and 3-4 digits (Use `[0-9]` to match a digit 0-9)
- `[-_\s]\d{1,2}` Match one of `-` `_` or a whitespace char
- `\s?,` Match an optional space and `,`

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

---

Using the lookbehind:

```
(?<=TCC(?:_BHPB)?\s\d{3,4})[-_\s]\d{1,2}\s?,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FswqgK/1)

Or if you want to match 1 or more spaces except a newline

```
\bTCC(?:_BHPB)?[\p{Zs}\t][0-9]{3,4}[-_\p{Zs}\t][0-9]{1,2}[\p{Zs}\t]*,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RjqUwH/1)